# Ajax async loading problems, data available but not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, asynchronous

this website is running on WP and I'm trying to load the page data through ajax. Mind you it's not posts I'm trying to load. For some reason it manages to load only 1 page properly, which is -what-articles.

IF I set async : false, all the data loads, but of course in such case for some reason my function which trims the data does not trim anything.

IF I leave async : true, then the data is available, but is only appended if I also add an alert(); function.

So it's something with the async method that bugs out.

Do not pay any heed to any other functions I'm running, with every other function disabled same stuff happens. I'm quite lost for ideas.

Code: http://pastebin.com/SgJLPXj0

Answer (score 0):

can you try using datatype as "text/html" and also remove async, cache property. If didn't comes up can u create dummy environment in http://jsfiddle.net/ or somewhere.

Comment: Well, with cache disabled, no other page which is supposed to be retrieved by ajax loads. Which makes sense, since the other pages were cached for me.
It doesn't seem to come up with anything at all. Basically still the data is appended only after an alert.

Comment: Rather than giving an alert can you wrap the below lines inside timeout fxn with 0 sec.

Comment: That is before the append.

Also tried fiddle, the same happens there.

Comment: Can u share that fiddle address

Comment: I may have found the culprit. If I call the function without any variables and just append the data with a preset link, it works.

Comment: Found the culprit. Good. If still finding any issue then share the fiddle url. Will fix it. Conversation Over.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was the click event that fired the function.